# Makefile: conditionals inside define

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to check that variable value is `yes` or `no`, but the following always fails:

```
FLAG1 ?= no
FLAG2 ?= yes

define check_
    ifneq ($(filter $(2),$($(1))),$($(1)))
        $(error Bad $(1) argument)
    endif
endef

$(call check_,FLAG1,yes no)
$(call check_,FLAG2,yes no)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For one, you add a space to the first parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FLAG1 ?= no
FLAG2 ?= yes

define check_
    $(if $(filter $($(1)),$(2)),,$(error BAD $(1) argument))
endef

$(call check_,FLAG1,yes no)
$(call check_,FLAG2,yes no)
```

Notice that you added a space before `FLAG1`, which means `$$(1)` resolves to `$( FLAG1)`, which in turn resolves to blank.   The next part is that I'm not sure about is the use if `ifneq` inside of a define.  You can use `$(if )` instead

----  EDIT ------

Actually, it's a combination of the missing space and @MadScientists answer...     The following also works:

```
define check_
    ifneq ($(filter $($(1)),$(2)),$($(1)))
        $$(error Bad $(1) argument [$($(1))] / [$(filter $($(1)),$(2))])
    endif
endef

$(eval $(call check_,FLAG1,yes no))
```

Thus `ifneq` can be used inside of a macro...   (and as @MadScientist pointed out, you have to escape the `$` in front of `$(error)` to prevent it from being expanded by call...)

Comment: Space was a typo, did not work without space either. Apparently, `ifeq`/`ifneq` do not work inside `define`, as you said.

Comment: The only issue with `filter` function is that `make FLAG1="yes no"` passes the test. Is there a simple fix?

Comment: You would have to do some trickery with `$(words)` like so: `$(if $(filter-out $(2),$($(1)))$(filter-out 1,$(words $($(1)))),$(error blah))`.    This would fail for any FLAG1 with more than one word.

Comment: I came up with this:
`$(filter $(addsuffix s,$(addprefix p,$(2))),p$($(1))s)`

Comment: Why do you not need to double the $ in front of filter and before the $(1) like so: `ifneq ($$(filter $$($(1)),$(2)),$$($(1)))`?
Doesn't `call` remove one layer for everything but the $(1) $(2) etc it inserts?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use plain `call` with a multi-line macro.  You have to use `$(eval $(call ...))` if the result of the `call` function consists of more than one line of makefile content.

You can use this:

```
define check_
    ifneq ($$(filter $(2),$$($(1))),$$($(1)))
        $$(error Bad $(1) argument)
    endif
endef
```

Basically, anything you want to be interpreted by the `eval` needs to be escaped so that `call` doesn't see it.

Comment: $(eval $(call ...)) did not help.
Looks like inside `check_` it translates `$$(1)` into `$1` instead of `$(FLAG1)`

Comment: If you use eval you need an extra level of escaping.  I'll update the answer.